# I want to make image slider but image is not visible on UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const Featured = () => {
    const sliders=[
      {
        url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ehizeex-shop/image/upload/v1672672076/NetflixApp/burger_emxbtv.jpg'
      },
    ]
    const [currentIndex,setCurrenindex]=useState(0) 
  return (
    <div className='max-w-[1520px] h-[500px] w-full py-4 px-4 relative'>
        <div className='w-full f-full rounded-2xl bg-center bg-cover duration-500'
        style={{backgroundImage: `url(${sliders[currentIndex].url})`}}>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

in div element i use style and give url of my img but it not visible on UI

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is with the child div, you need to use h-full to have a proper height and after that the image will appear.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
export const Featured = () => {
    const sliders=[
      {
        url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/ehizeex-shop/image/upload/v1672672076/NetflixApp/burger_emxbtv.jpg'
      },
    ]
    const [currentIndex,setCurrenindex]=useState(0) 
  return (
    <div className='max-w-[1520px] h-[500px] w-full py-4 px-4 relative'>
        <div className='w-full h-full rounded-2xl bg-center bg-cover duration-500'
        style={{backgroundImage: `url(${sliders[currentIndex].url})`}}>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```